# Order the x-axis in ggplot based on the exact order in my table

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the data frame:

```
structure(list(`Number of patents` = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L), .Label = c("0-9", 
"10-19", "100-199", "20-29", "200-299", "30-39", "300-399", "40-49", 
"400-499", "50-74", "500-999", "75-99", "Over 1000"), class = "factor"), 
    `Number of companies` = c(397, 102, 54, 30, 18, 35, 22, 39, 
    28, 13, 11, 34, 69)), .Names = c("Number of patents", "Number of companies"
), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

When I use ggplot, it reorders my x-acis "Number of patents" numerically so instead of going "0-9", "10-19", "20-29", "30-39", it changes the order to:

"0-9", "10-19", "100-199", "20-29", etc. which of course makes no sense. Is there any way that I can force R to just keep the same ordering as the data frame that I try to plot from?

This is my ggplot:

```
ggplot(companiesoverpatents, aes(x= `Number of patents`, y= `Number of companies`)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", fill = "#00AFBB") +
  ggtitle("Companies over patents")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it makes some sense because *number of patents* is ordered alphabetically. To achieve what you want you need to change the order of levels in `factor`:

```
companiesoverpatents$`Number of patents` <- factor(companiesoverpatents$`Number of patents`, levels = unique(companiesoverpatents$`Number of patents`))
```

As a side note, try to avoid spaces in column names.

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-level the factors in your dataset:

```
companiesoverpatents[,1]<-factor(unlist(companiesoverpatents[,1]),levels=unlist(companiesoverpatents[,1]))
```